# Why does C# code that converts Avro files to Msgpack files get much slower over time?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection, cpu-usage

I've written some code which converts a large number of [avro data files](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spec.html#Object+Container+Files), specified via the cmd line, to zstd-compressed msgpack files.

When I get the program to convert lots of files, each containing 20,000+ records, it gets significantly slower over time. The memory usage seems quite stable, but the CPU usage increases significantly.

Can anybody spot what might be causing my problem? Or give me advice on how to find it? Could it be to do with garbage collection? I'm using the [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) NuGet package, as well as [Message Pack for C#](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) and [ZstdNet](https://github.com/skbkontur/ZstdNet).

```
foreach (var path in options.Paths)
{
    var outputFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(options.OutputDir, path),
        "msgpack.zst");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFilePath)!);
    await using var outputFile = File.Create(outputFilePath);
    await using var compressedStream =
        new CompressionStream(outputFile);
    using var dataFileReader =
        DataFileReader<BinanceDepthMessage>.OpenReader(path);
    foreach (var depthMessage in dataFileReader.NextEntries)
    {
        var mappedDepthMessage = new BinanceDepthUpdate
        {
            E = depthMessage.e,
            E1 = depthMessage.E,
            T = depthMessage.T,
            S = depthMessage.s,
            U = depthMessage.U,
            U1 = depthMessage.u,
            Pu = depthMessage.pu,
            B = depthMessage.b,
            A = depthMessage.a
        };
        await compressedStream.WriteAsync(
            MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(mappedDepthMessage));
    }
    Log.Information("Converted file: {Path}", path);
}
```

Comment: If you think it's a garbage collection problem, use Performance Monitor (aka Perfmon) and the .NET Memory counters.  Pay attention to Gen2 garbage collections and Large Object Heap use.

Comment: Have you profiled these calls to see which take increasingly longer? Or even just whacked a breakpoint in live, after it's been running for a minute and single stepped and looked at the timings?

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for the tip - will investigate that further.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks also, another useful suggestion. When you say "looked at the timings", is it possible to see how long a call takes in IDE when "single stepping" in debug mode? I'm using Rider not VS.

Comment: oof.. I dont know about rider but jetbrains always did really smart ahead-of-the-game stuff; I'd be amazed if it wasn't in there.. If you can post a complete minimum repro that I can run in VS I can see if I see the same slowdown

Comment: A stopwatch and some logging could probably help you determine timings

Comment: Rider has a profiler included which you can use